# How to switch between two images using drag and drop in one specific horizontal layout in Android?

Tags: android, image, drag-and-drop

I want to switch between any two images among four images in different views or different layout using Dragged and Dropped.

If A image is dropped to the particular B image which is arranged in Horizontal line,the B image is automatically arrange to the A image's position.

```
class MyDragListener implements OnDragListener {
Drawable enterShape = getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.shape_droptarget);
Drawable normalShape = getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.shape);

@Override
public boolean onDrag(View v, DragEvent event) {
  int action = event.getAction();
  switch (event.getAction()) {
  case DragEvent.ACTION_DRAG_STARTED:
    // Do nothing
    break;
  case DragEvent.ACTION_DRAG_ENTERED:
    v.setBackgroundDrawable(enterShape);
    break;
  case DragEvent.ACTION_DRAG_EXITED:
    v.setBackgroundDrawable(normalShape);
    break;
  case DragEvent.ACTION_DROP:
    // Dropped, reassign View to ViewGroup
    View view = (View) event.getLocalState();
    ViewGroup owner = (ViewGroup) view.getParent();
    owner.removeView(view);
    LinearLayout container = (LinearLayout) v;
    container.addView(view);
    view.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
    break;
  case DragEvent.ACTION_DRAG_ENDED:
    v.setBackgroundDrawable(normalShape);
  default:
    break;
  }
  return true;
}
```

Comment: It would be great if you can share your progress / Code or any issues that you are getting?

Comment: Actually i found another way to do this using views..

Comment: But its not working...please give me some idea about this .

Comment: heyy bro i already stuck to implement exactly like this type of requirment since last 15 days...can u implement this??? please help me.

Comment: Try public boolean onTouch(View view, MotionEvent me) method..